# Condition with dates on Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a function that flags the rows based on certain conditions.

It's not working and I think it's caused by the format of the columns.

The function is:

```
tolerance=5

def pmm_m2_rag(data):

    if  data['m2'] == data['TP_M2'] and data['m6p'] + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D') <= data['latedate']:
        return 'GREEN'


    elif data['m2']!= data['TP_M2'] and data['m6p'] + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D') < data['latedate']:
        return 'AMBER'


    elif data['m2']!= None and data['m6p'] + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D') > data['latedate']:
        return 'RED'
```

The dataframe is :

```
                m2       TP_M2         m6p          latedate         
0       2019-11-28  2019-10-29  2020-02-21        2020-02-25       
1       2019-11-28  2019-10-29  2020-02-21        2020-02-25       
2       2019-11-28  2019-11-28  2020-02-09        2020-02-17       
3       2019-11-28  2019-11-28  2020-02-29        2020-02-17
```

The datatype is:

```
m2                  object
TP_M2               object
m6p                 object
latedate    object
dtype: object
```

Expected output:

```
                m2       TP_M2         m6p          latedate         RAG
0       2019-11-28  2019-10-29  2020-02-21        2020-02-25       AMBER
1       2019-11-28  2019-10-29  2020-02-21        2020-02-25       AMBER
2       2019-11-28  2019-11-28  2020-02-09        2020-02-17       GREEN
3       2019-11-28  2019-11-28  2020-02-29        2020-02-17         RED
```

Comment: i debugged my program and seems that the error come from this line: data['m6p'] + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D') < data['latedeliverydate'] or data['latedeliverydate'] > data['m6p'] + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D')

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: `data` is a complete dataframe, right? The error message tells you, that it is nonsense to evaluate a dataframe in an if-statement. What you most likely want is to apply `pmm_m2_rag` to each row in the dataframe.

Comment: data = data.applymap(pd.to_datetime)

Comment: yes data is a complete dataframe

Comment: Your conditions are clearly wrong, take a look at the amber one if you just test the  filter only the third one is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, something in your code seems to be wrong. This

```
... unit='D') <= data['latedate'] < data['m6p'] ...
```

chaining of comparisons is definitely wrong.

Then in your conditon for *AMBER* the two clauses of you `or` are identical. This also makes no sense.

Apart from that you should convert the datatypes of your columns to type `datetime`. E.g. by:

```
data = data.applymap(pd.to_datetime)
```

This depends on what the datatype is when you read from your database.

After that, there are basically two options. You can write a function that takes a single row, calculates the value and returns the *color*. Then apply this function row by row.

The other (faster and preferrable) option is to calculate the column 'RAG' in parallel.

This can be done by using `numpy.where` with the conditions you have written above.
Please note that `and` between datafram columns has to be written as `&`; `or` as `|`.

Something like this should work:

```py
import numpy as np
def pmm_m2_rag(data):
    green_filter = (data.m2 == data.TP_M2) & \
        (data.m6p + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D') <= data.latedate)

    amber_filter = (data.m2 != data.TP_M2) & \
        (data.m6p + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D') < data.latedate) | \
        (data.latedate > data.m6p + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D'))

    red_filter = (data.m2 != pd.NaT) & \
        (data.m6p + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D') > data.latedate)

    data['RAG'] = np.where(green_filter, 'GREEN', np.where(amber_filter, 'AMBER', np.where(red_filter, 'RED', '')))
```

The syntax of `np.where` is

```
np.where(<CONDITION>, true-clause, false-clause)
```

Comment: Indeed there was a mistake on my condition which i changed in my code.

Comment: I changed the code but it's gives only the Red condition

Comment: I added the code i use updated with the condition as an answer

Answer (score 1):

one option it to convert `object` into `datetime` before doing the `datetime` comparisons as below

```py
from datetime import datetime
tolerance=5

def pmm_m2_rag(data):
    #m2 = datetime.strptime(data['m2'],'%Y-%m-%d')
    #m6p = datetime.strptime(data['m6p'],'%Y-%m-%d')
    #latedate = datetime.strptime(data['latedate'],'%Y-%m-%d')
    #TP_M2 = datetime.strptime(data['TP_M2'],'%Y-%m-%d')
    m2 = datetime.strptime(str(data['m2']),'%Y-%m-%d')
    m6p = datetime.strptime(str(data['m6p']),'%Y-%m-%d')
    latedate = datetime.strptime(str(data['latedate']),'%Y-%m-%d')
    TP_M2 = datetime.strptime(str(data['TP_M2']),'%Y-%m-%d')
    if  m2 == TP_M2 and m6p + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D') <= latedate:
        return 'GREEN'


    elif m2!= TP_M2 and m6p + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D') < latedate:
        return 'AMBER'


    elif m2!= None and m6p + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D') > latedate:
        return 'RED'
df['RAG'] = df.apply(pmm_m2_rag, axis=1)
```

Comment: i am having this error TypeError: ('strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.date', 'occurred at index 0')
Comes from: m2 = datetime.strptime(data['m2'],'%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: So, the datatype of column is datetime. How you are creating the dataframe ? can you paste it in your question ?

Comment: m2 is an object i posted the datatypes of the column
i am importing the dataframe from a database

Comment: If datatype is datetime, then no need to parse it again. You can use it as such. When I copy paste your sample data, datatype of every column is showing as `object`.
One workaround is use `str`, to convert the column values to string before parsing. I edited my answer.

Comment: I keep getting this one now: 
ValueError: ("time data 'NaT' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'", 'occurred at index 6')

Comment: Its caused by the presence of NaT

Comment: My code works with your sample data. Provide your data which causes error, then I can find the issue.